# UITextField with DatePicker crashes

Tags: ios, swift, selector, uidatepicker

I am new to iOS/Swift so please bear with me.

I have a TextField, timeTextField, and want to display a TimePicker on click. All this is working property but when another element is selected the app crashes why does it crash?
**UPDATE 1: updated code**
code:

```
func setupTimePicker(){
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    datePickerView.removeFromSuperview()
    timeTextField.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    var date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    date = sender.date;

    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)

    timeTextField.text = String(format: "%02d", hour) + ":" + String(format: "%02d", minutes)
}
```

error:

> [TestApp.ViewController pickTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9305e08e20

Comment: Check your `timeTextField` instance is properly connected(IBOutlet).

Comment: Do you have a `func pickTime(...)` somewhere in your code? Or did you had previously one? If YES, check your Storyboard, your UIViewController class isn't correct, or you have an old IBOutlet for an IBAction there.

Comment: I previously had one and forgot to remove it from my scoreboard, like I said i'm new to iOS so it is a rookie mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `iOS8/iOS9`, when you added a view as `inputView` to `UITextField` app crashes. To resolve your crash, before adding `datePicker` as `inputView` to `UITextField` call `[<pickerView> removeFromSuperView]`. This will solve crash issue.

Comment: If i change my code to:
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
        datePickerView.removeFromSuperview()
        timeTextField.inputView = datePickerView
It still crashes

Comment: Problem is that you have a IBAction method i.e "pickTime" added in your storyboard for some button and you missed to implement the same in your controller file. This is not related to UITextField input view what you are suspecting. Check your storyboard / xib IBActions for all the buttons in your controller.

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks, I missed that on completely.

Comment: even in ios11, a crash is there, but removing it from picker solved the problem.Thanks.